# Вывод ячейки с наибольшим количеством совпадений со списком

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имею фрейм данных:

```
d = {'name': ['mike, rick, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', None], 'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Также список:

```
['carl', 'nick', 'morty', 'homer', 'rick', 'bart', 'mike']
```

Нужно значение фрейма с наибольшим количеством совпадений значений со списком (последовательность не важна), а также количество повторений данного совпадения, а именно:

```
'mike, rick, morty'
1
```

Comment: В той же последовательности должны совпадения быть, я так понимаю? Зачем это вообще, или учебная задача?

Comment: Последовательность не важна. А спрашиваю, потому что find и for решить можно, но это не то. Это одна из идей решения учебной задачи, поэтому обрисовал утрированно. Хочу знать все способы чисто для самообразования.

Comment: Нет, вы всё же опишите нормально что такое "совпадение", поскольку все эти слова там есть. Они должны идти "без разрывов" или как вообще? Я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону `n-грамм`. Т.е. выделять последовательности длиной `n` из списка, а потом искать их в данных. Причём, начинать с максимальной клины и уменьшать потом длину понемногу.

Comment: Совпадение в данном случае- это ячейка с наибольшим количеством этих же слов в любой последовательности из данного списка. Изменил задание для большего понимания.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421046/counting-length-of-intersection-of-a-list-with-pandas-column-of-lists

Comment: @splash58 Да, вот это похоже должно взлететь `df['col1'].explode().isin(panel).sum(level=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из предложенного в комментариях у меня получилось это:

```
d = {'name': ['mike, rick, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', None], 
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
pan = ['carl', 'nick', 'morty', 'homer', 'rick', 'bart', 'mike']

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['max_in'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', ') if x else ['']).explode().isin(pan).sum(level=0)
df[df.max_in==df.max_in.max()]
```

вывод:

```
    name                        Date        Address max_in
0   mike, rick, morty           11/05/2011  AR      3
3   rick, reaven, bart, homer   12/20/2020  EU      3
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Согласно последнему комментарию к вопросу получилась гораздо более объёмная конструкция.